# CKEditor Zoom plugin : Text is not wrapping on zoom

Tags: ckeditor

> The default CKEditor zoom plugin is not wrapping the content on zooming in IE10 browser

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: We have default ckeditor zoom plugin, when we try to use zoom  plugin the text content doesn't wrap in the window. we are getting x and y scroll bars.

Comment: Zoom is not maintained by CKEditor team. You should report a bug to the author of the [plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/zoom).

Comment: Thanks for the reply oleq, please help where to report this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'zoom',
{
requires : [ 'richcombo' ],

init : function( editor )
{
    var config = editor.config;

    // Inject basic sizing for the pane as the richCombo doesn't allow to specify it
    var node = CKEDITOR.document.getHead().append( 'style' );
    node.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
    var content = '.cke_combopanel__zoom { height: 200px; width: 100px; }' +
                '.cke_combo__zoom .cke_combo_text { width: 40px;}';

    if ( CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.version<11 )
        node.$.styleSheet.cssText = content;
    else
        node.$.innerHTML = content;

    editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'Zoom',
        {
            label : 'Zoom',
            title : 'Zoom',
            multiSelect : false,
            className : 'zoom',
            modes:{wysiwyg:1,source:1 },

            panel :
            {
                css : [ CKEDITOR.skin.getPath( 'editor' ) ].concat( config.contentsCss )
            },

            init : function()
            {
                var zoomOptions = [50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200, 400],
                    zoom;

                this.startGroup( 'Zoom level' );
                // Loop over the Array, adding all items to the combo.
                for ( var i = 0 ; i < zoomOptions.length ; i++ )
                {
                    zoom = zoomOptions[ i ];
                    // value, html, text
                    this.add( zoom + "", zoom + " %", zoom + " %" );
                }
                // Default value on first click
                this.setValue("100", "100 %");
            },

            onClick : function( sValue )
            {
                var body = editor.editable().$;
                var value = parseInt(sValue);

                body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "top left";
                body.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + (value/100)  + ")";

                body.style.WebkitTransformOrigin = "top left";
                body.style.WebkitTransform = "scale(" + (value/100)  + ")";

                body.style.OTransformOrigin = "top left";
                body.style.OTransform = "scale(" + (value/100)  + ")";

                body.style.TransformOrigin = "top left";
                body.style.Transform = "scale(" + (value/100)  + ")";
                // IE
                body.style.zoom = value/100;

                this.setValue( sValue, sValue + " %");
                this.lastValue = sValue;
            },

            onRender: function() {
                editor.on( 'mode', function( ev ) {
                    // Restore zoom level after switching from Source mode
                    if (this.lastValue)
                        this.onClick( this.lastValue );

                }, this );
            }
        });
    // End of richCombo element

} //Init
} );
```

Comment: This is not working , the text content is not wrapping we are getting x and y scroll bars.

Comment: @Alfonsoml can you please help santosh on this issue.